# All available key-value properties like spring.rabbitmq.xyz

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

what are all spring.rabbitmq.xyz key-value properties avaliable we can use in application. More over where i can find the reference of these

Answer (score 0):

See the appendix to the boot reference manual https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.5.RELEASE/reference/html/common-application-properties.html